# images on titanium apps look distorted on iphone

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I am using the following function:

```
var b4 = Titanium.UI.createButton({
title : '',
top : 360,
width : 190,
height : 20,
backgroundImage : '../images/signup.gif',
});

win.add(b4);
```

When I deploy to the iphone, the button above looks distorted (only the lower part of the sign up button shows). Now sure what to do...
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to make your button as a view instead, i.e.

```
var button = Ti.UI.createView({
    top: 360,
    width: 190,
    height: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#777777'
})


button.add(Ti.UI.createImageView({
    top: 10,
    bottom: 10,
    image: '../images/signup.gif'
}))

win.add(button);
```